# String matching in php not working correctly?

Tags: php, string

`stristr($post['message'],$t1)=== FALSE` gives a list of results but I need `stristr($post['message'],$t1)=== TRUE`, that gives only 1 result !
help plz.,

**CODE:**

```
 foreach($page_posts['data'] as $post){
        if(!(stristr($post['message'],$t1)=== FALSE) && $t1!==" ")
        { 
        $message = (($post['message']) ? $post['message'] : " ");
        $i++;
        print($message);
        }
```

same as `stristr($post['message'],$t1)=== TRUE` i.e.; gives one result only ~

Comment: what are you trying to do, and what is $t1?

Answer (score 2):

stristr will NOT return boolean TRUE... it will return string when the string you are looking for is found. Otherwise, it will return boolean FALSE.

http://www.php.net/stristr

so testing with stristr($post['message'],$t1)=== TRUE is wrong.

Comment: thanks I just want reverse operation of  stristr($post['message'],$t1)=== FALSE , thats why I used '!' sign.

Answer (score 0):

Use stripos, not stristr.

```
if(stripos($post['message'], $t1) > -1) {
  // needle is in haystack
}
```

Comment: then it's time you start echoing what's in $post['message'] and in $t1, and put that information in your question, to show those who might want to answer you what your data and needles are. Because this guaranteed works, which suggests your $t1 really doesn't exist in your data

Comment: that's great: so show us. update your question to show what's in $page_posts['data'], and what's in $t1, so that we can see the whole problem.